# Interpreting Odds Ratio for a Continuous Variable in a Fractional Logit Model

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio, quasi-likelihood

I am using proportion to data to measure the effect of several variables on on lameness level (continuous variable, given as % of herd lame). Ideally I would have the counts to model it as over-dispersed Poisson data, which has been previously used for this dataset but the counts are missing for the variable I need to use. The best solution I have come up with is a fractional logit model, which I believe using a glm with quasi-binomial errors in R, should approximate to this in STATA, but I am having a problem interpreting the odds ratios for continuous variables for this model.

```
model1 <- glm(Lameness.level ~ Continuous.Variable, data = my.data, family = quasibinomial(link = 'logit'))
```

As far as I understand, the odds ratio given is the odds ratio for a one unit increase in the explanatory variable, and I am getting on OR of 90.0 for the one unit increase.  Am I correct in that since the OR is interpreted as the unit increase from 0 to 1 (e.g. the OR between having 0% lame and 100% of my herd lame), rather than the units in between (as I was perhaps naively hoping R would give me the OR for)? Is there a way to alter the OR so that is given for a different one unit increase (e.g, 0.01, so corresponding to an 1% increase in lameness)?

Or alternatively, is there another way that I could model this data given that it is missing the counts?

Comment: It is for a unit increase in the predictor variable not, as you seem to suggest, for a unit increase in the outcome.

Comment: Sorry, slightly bad explanation on my part. The predictor variable also involves 0-100% of the herd, which I realise reads slightly confusingly. I realise that the odds ratio is for the unit increase in the predictor variable, but my question is, is there a way to model this so that the unit increase is for e.g. 0.01, so a 1% increase in the predictor variable rather than the jump from 0-1, which is corresponding to 0 and 100%.

Comment: Try multiplying the predictor by 100?

Comment: Thank you,  this does make the odds ratio much more interpretable!